# Vue.js Transitions - 1st Entrance Not Working

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I made a [Code Sandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/zq5x5vpozm) to illustrate a vue transition not working on its initial appearance.

I'm using the following css to achieve the slide-in-slide-out effect:

```
.slide-fade-enter-active
  transition: all 2s ease;

.slide-fade-leave-active 
  transition: all 2s ease;

.slide-fade-enter
  // /* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */
  transform: translateX(40px) !important;
  opacity: 0;

.slide-fade-leave-to
  transform: translateX(-40px);
  opacity: 0;
```

---

I had figured that the `slide-fade-enter` would still apply, even if it was the initial rendering of the component.

What am I missing in my sass to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To make transitions work on initial render make sure to add the `appear` attribute

```
<transition
  appear
  appear-class="custom-appear-class"
  appear-to-class="custom-appear-to-class" 
  appear-active-class="custom-appear-active-class">
  ...
</transition>
```

Ref:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render